# RowDelete functionality does not refresh label field

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, devexpress

I have an `ASP.net` with `C#` web app with an issue. On the app, the user can enter some data and click an "Add" button. This will generate a grid on the screen with the data the user just entered. There is also a text box for "Total Amount Requested". Below that, there is a label for "Remaining Amount". If the user puts 100.00 in the "Total Amount Requested" and then loads 75.00 into the grid, the "Remaining Amount" will show "25.00". This works fine. I added a delete row to the grid, so the user can delete specific rows. This also works. I added a _RowDeleted function to the grid, and then inserted the function to do the math for "Remaining Amount". Here is the issue:

When I delete the row, it deletes from the database, no issue. However, the label on the screen does not refresh. I put a stop in the code and walked through it. The script works, the label.text is loaded with what I expect, but it just won't refresh on screen. I've tried many different things but keep hitting a wall. Any help would be appreciated!

The Grid:

```
 <dx:ASPxGridView ID="gridGL1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
 DataSourceID="sdsGLData" KeyFieldName="GenLedgerID" OnRowDeleted="gridGL1_RowDeleted">
     <Columns>
     <dx:GridViewCommandColumn VisibleIndex="0" Caption=" " ButtonType="Button">
         <DeleteButton Visible="True">
         </DeleteButton>
     </dx:GridViewCommandColumn>
 <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="GenLedgerID" Visible="false" VisibleIndex="1">
 </dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
 <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="UnitNumber" VisibleIndex="2">
 </dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
 <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="AccountNumber" VisibleIndex="3">
 </dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
 <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="Amount" VisibleIndex="4">
 </dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
 </Columns>
 <SettingsBehavior ConfirmDelete="True" />
 </dx:ASPxGridView>
```

The SDS:

```
 <asp:SqlDataSource ID="sdsGLData" runat="server" 
      ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:FEAPConnectionString %>" 
      ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:FEAPConnectionString.ProviderName %>" 
      SelectCommand="prcRequestGLList" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure"
      DeleteCommand="delete RequestsGL where GenLedgerID = @GenLedgerID">
      <SelectParameters>
         <asp:Parameter Direction="ReturnValue" Name="RETURN_VALUE" Type="Int32" />
         <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="lblUserID" Name="UserID" PropertyName="Text" 
                    Type="String" />
         <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="txtRequestDate" Name="RequestDate" 
                    PropertyName="Text" Type="DateTime" />
      </SelectParameters>
 </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

The _RowDeleted

```
protected void gridGL1_RowDeleted(object sender, DevExpress.Web.Data.ASPxDataDeletedEventArgs e)
{
    RemainingTotal();
}
```

The RemainingTotal():

```
protected void RemainingTotal()
{
    TotalGLAmount();

    decimal TotalReq;
    decimal TotalGL;

    // Total Requested Amount
    if (txtTotalAmount.Text == "")
    {
        TotalReq = 0.00M;
    }
    else
    {
        TotalReq = Convert.ToDecimal(txtTotalAmount.Text);
    }

    // Total GL Amount
    if (lblTotalGLAmount.Text == "")
    {
        TotalGL = 0.00M;
    }
    else
    {
        TotalGL = Convert.ToDecimal(lblTotalGLAmount.Text);
    }

    // Total Remaining Amount
    if (TotalReq != TotalGL)
    {

        lblRemainingAmount.Text = Convert.ToString(TotalReq - TotalGL);

        lblTest.Text = Convert.ToString(TotalReq - TotalGL);

        if (TotalReq > TotalGL)
        {
            lblRemainingAmount.ForeColor = Color.Black;
        }
        else if (TotalReq < TotalGL)
        {
            lblRemainingAmount.ForeColor = Color.Red;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (txtTotalAmount.Text != "")
        {
            lblRemainingAmount.Text = "<b>EVEN!</b>";
            lblRemainingAmount.ForeColor = Color.Black;

            lblTest.Text = "<b>EVEN!</b>";
        }
        else
        {
            lblRemainingAmount.Text = "0.00";
            lblRemainingAmount.ForeColor = Color.Black;

            lblTest.Text = "0.00";
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check these threads:

[The concept of callbacks - Why is it impossible to update external control data during a callback to another control](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/KA18609)

[ASPxGridView - How to update an external control during a callback](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Example/Details/E2379)